# Count number of rows that contain same value?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame that contains two columns "a" and "b". I would like to count the number of rows that contain the same value for both columns for a given row.

E.g. If row 1 of column "a" contains "blue" 
     If row 1 of column "b" contains "blue" than that will count as 1.

Comment: length(which(df$a==df$b))

Comment: or even `sum(df$a == df$b)`

Comment: @CalumYou yours will fail if an "NA" value exists! Chuck in a sneaky na.rm=TRUE ;)

Comment: What do you want to do if both columns are `NA`?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth, yours too: `length(which(NA==NA))`.

Comment: Perhaps `sum((is.na(df$a) & is.na(df$b)) | (df$a==df$b), na.rm=TRUE)`, if `NA==NA` is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Something as simple as `sum(df$a == df$b)` will give you the right answer, *assuming there are no `NA` in the data*.

If you want to be safe, you can use something like this:

```
`%==%` <- function(a,b) {
  ana <- is.na(a)
  bna <- is.na(b)
  (ana & bna) | (!ana & !bna & a==b)
}
x1 <- c(1,2,NA,4)
x2 <- c(2,2,NA,NA)
x1 %==% x2
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
sum(x1 %==% x2)
# [1] 2
```